# Issue with Expo 50: Unable to Generate Working Development Build

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I recently updated my application from Expo 49 to Expo 50, and I'm encountering difficulties in generating a working development build.

When I try to run the code on my Android 13 device, I'm getting the following error:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBTgA.jpg)

I also tried creating a new project, followed the tutorial for creating a development build (https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/create-a-build/), and successfully built the project. However, even in this case, when I launch the code from the development build, I get the same error.

I've already updated both Node (v20.11.0) and JDK (20.0.2).
Has anyone else experienced a similar issue?

Comment: have you tried running `npx expo-doctor` and afterwards, if no errors were returned, `eas build --profile development --platform android --clear-cache`?